# How do you Loop through a specific Textboxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have found code that will allow me to loop through every textbox on a form and then allow me to compare it against some criteria.  But thats not what i want to do.  I know the 4 textboxes i want to loop through, i just don't know how to refer to those 4, without looping through every textbox on the form.  Which from my program point of view isn't really an issue as i'll only have about 20 textboxes in total.  But that isn't the point, i want to know how to do it propperly.

Basically i have 4 Textboxes : MyTxtBox1, MyTxtBox2, MyTxtBox3 and MyTxtBox4.  And its only these i want to loop through.

Something along the lines of:

```
          for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
          {   
    string myName = "MyTxtBox" + i.ToString();
            if (MyFunction(this.myName))
            {
                return;
            }
          }
```

But this.myName doesn't work and thats probably because its just a string.  I don't know how i can refer to the textbox on the form after i've built the textbox name as a string.

Can anyone see what it is i'm trying to do and is it even possible?  Or will i have to loop through every textbox on the form and then test against its .Name property.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? When you already know the name, why you want to loop through???

Comment: Does your function 'MyFunction(this.myName))' is a bool function? What does it returns, would be better if you post your function too!

Comment: If always the same 4, why not reference them explicitly? Also, share `MyFunction` please.

Comment: Also dont use this.myName, try only 'myName' as argument

Answer (score 3):

A textbox is a Control. Create a ControlCollection and then use the [ControlCollection.Find()](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx&ei=cLSmTf-8KoK4rAe0zOjtCQ&usg=AFQjCNHDR0oQxbUpBq0asgQxy_H4IX5Tig&sig2=x51dJ347eUFv7YV_YNMVYg)method...  Something like

```
Control.ControlCollection collection = this.Controls;
Control newControl=collection.Find(<textbox name here>,true);
```

and run it thru the required loop.

Comment: +1: This the best idea as the text boxes will all be members of the collection anyway (or at least somewhere in the control hierarchy).

Comment: +1: This is correct. I am posting another similar answer that more closely matches OP's code, and also includes a (TextBox) type cast, which is needed to actually reference the properties of the individual text boxes.

Comment: Thanks Khemka, this looks like it is exactly the sort of thing i was after.  But for some reason i can't get Control.ControlCollection to work.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010.  I get the following error:  "Error 1 The type name 'ControlCollection' does not exist in the type 'System.Windows.Controls.Control'".    When i type Control. the intellisense doesn't offer ControlCollection as an option.  If i add   "using System.Windows.Forms" i get an error "'Control' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Controls.Control' and 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'"

Comment: @FrustratedNewbie, using System.Windows.Forms worked perfectly for me. But I hadn't included System.Windows.Controls.Control.

Answer (score 1):

Think about something along the lines of this:

```
{
    List<Textbox> list = new List<Textbox>();
    list.Add(myBox1);
    list.Add(myBox1);
    ..

    foreach (Textbox box in list)
        if (MyFuction(box))
            return;
}
```

Comment: I had this suggested to me, and it would work for my small number of items.  But again if i had 20 or more this would become more and more cumbersome.  And i'm sure there must be a way to iterate through a loop.  Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I am not sure what you mean then-- if you only add the four you want to loop through to the list, then all the others won't be looped through on your form. No matter if you have 10, 20 or a 100.

Comment: Sorry, i meant that your solution is great for my current problem, as you are correct i only have 4 textboxes.  But in the future i may want to iterate through 20 or more textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing them into a groupbox together, that way you can access all the controls of that groupbox.

Answer (score 0):

this.Controls["yourtextboxname" + Convert.ToString(i + 1)].Text;